# Access sometimes jumps to existing record on save new record - Access2k FE/SQL2005 BE

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, ms-access, vba

I am really posting this out of desperation after searching around a lot for an answer and trying a few different things with no success.

I have an Access database where I have recently migrated the tables to SQL 2005, Access continues to function to the users as a front-end providing forms, reports, and queries.

However, since moving to the Access FE/SQL BE setup, the users have been reporting that *sometimes*, when they are entering a new record, they click into a subform (saving the record) or click save on the menu itself, it jumps to an existing record. The new record has been saved, but for some reason access switches to a different record as it refreshes. The user then has to close out, find the saved record, and continue editing it.

> **Scenario**: A user is entering a quote and fills out all the quote details, customer,
>   date, etc,  then clicks in the line-items subform to add a product (or clicks save in the menu), and suddenly
>   the quote form (and line-item subform) is showing the details of some random quote. The random quote could be recent, or from years ago, and has nothing in common with the quote they were entering.

This weird behavior only happens on inserting a new record, never on editing an existing record. Users tell me that it happens '*more often*' when they go to add a new (quote, customer, whatever)  after opening the database.

I have noticed it is only happening on forms that have subforms, so my first thought is that it had to do with Access sending through the subform data before the form data is saved, causing a PK violation. But this doesn't appear to be happening: there are no errors on the SQL server, and the record is successfully saved. Forcing the users to save the main form record before adding subform records (i.e. on a quote, forcing them to save the quote before they can add line items) didn't work, it just causes the jump (sometimes) on the save.

It isn't vba running on the save or on current, I have set breakpoints on all the event handlers as it jumps and no vba is being executed. Some of the 'jumping' forms have no vba on the form. But all have subforms. I suspect it has to do with record locking.

The server running the tables is SQL Server 2005, the users are using a mix of Access 2000 and 2003, mostly XP SP3 with a couple of old Win2k boxes. They are using Merge replication and a couple of users are running replicated SSEE2005 editions and subscribing to the main server. Most users are not replicated, just connecting directly to the server via ODBC or SQL native client connections. But I have verified that this is happening to all users, usually once or twice a day, and it has happened to me before. So it isn't a user issue.

The worst part about this behavior is that it only happens some of the time and I haven't managed to find a scenario that will **always** cause it to happen.

If anyone has experienced anything like this before, please let me know how you sorted it out, or even suggestions would be welcome.

**Update:** 
(1/10/09) Problem solved, thanks to David Fenton. Setting the form to Data Entry mode (Form.DataEntry = true) before opening it to add records does indeed prevent the jumping. Client reports no issues at all since I changed this a week ago.

Comment: Are you using primary keys and a TimeStamp aka RowVersion on all tables?   I assume you are using primary keys as you sound quite competent but I have to ask.

Comment: Yes, all tables have a PK and identity. I tried adding TimeStamp on one pair of tables (the Quote and line items) and it didn't make any difference to this problem.

Comment: (Tony, you can copy your comment to clipboard, delete it and, and then replace it with a new comment with your corrections)

Comment: FWIW TimeStamp columns are a good thing as far as Access is concerned. Please add those to all the tables. There are osme KB articles, etc on the topic but I don't have them right at my fingerprints.   @David, thanks.  I hadn't notice that little grey x before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A client is reporting occasional similar problems.  It started immediately after they started using merge replication.

I've informed several contacts within the Microsoft Access product group as well as my fellow Access and SQL Server MVPs.

Please email me your email address so I can forward that to my contacts at Microsoft as I would assume they would want to contact you directly.  tony at granite.ab.ca

BTW excellent trouble shooting and detailed problem description.

Comment: Stupid question.   Can you turn off merge replication for a while to see if that does indeed cause the problem?

Comment: Question for you: Did you check the conflict viewer to see if any conflicts are logged.    Comment:  Something similar happens in Access when you have uniqueidentifier as primary key in sql server table, or some other field type with self generated value. Do you have int with identity as PK? Any triggers?

Comment: mmhh! Are you thinking of something that happens at synch time? Interesting!

Comment: Actually I'm forwarding on the comments of my fellow Access and SQL Server MVPs who have more experience in this area than I do.

Comment: @Tony, I will create a copy of the database and run it without merge replication and see if I can get it to jump. I don't think any conflicts are being logged but I will check again and update this thread with results.

Comment: Also you haven't yet answered "Do you have int with identity as PK? Any triggers? "

Comment: Autonumber with identity is PK, no triggers apart from the ones belonging to Merge replication

Comment: Good.     Now the bit about triggers belonging to Merge replication is quite interesting but I'm not going to dig much further on that one as I don't know much about SQL Server.   Also my contacts in Microsoft are doing some "following up" on this issue internally.

Answer (score 4):

It definitely sounds like a record locking issue. Are you using autonumbers as PK? Have you tried 2 computers adding a record on the same form at the same time (meaning one of them will fire the insert event while the other has added a new record on the form one but is still editing it)?

Could you check in a way or another if the PK of the inserted record *after* insertion in the table stays similar to the PK given before the insertion (by adding for example a few 'debug.print's to your code)?

A scenario could be 2 pending inserts been given by the machine the same PK, the second one being then automatically changed at insert time, resulting in your form loosing the 'active' record.

Comment: Thanks that is a good suggestion Philippe, but I don't think it could be the cause of the problem. Yes, PK is autonumber on both the objects in form and in the subform but I don't think it is PK because it is also happening on replicated clients, not only are they not on the network, they have partitioned PK segments.

Comment: Then I am convinced it has something to do with this autonumber issue. By the way, partitioned autonumber PK segments are really a pita! I guess autonumbers were inherited from an Access upgrade to SQL server.

Answer (score 3):

I'm wondering about the scenario where you are using a form to add records that has any other records for the user to jump to.

That is, I don't believe in using the same form to edit records as is used to create them.

Instead, I use an unbound dialog to collect all the required fields, insert the record in SQL, then open the main editing form to that single record (not a form with the whole table navigated to the record that was just added).

Keep in mind that in a main form/subform scenario, creating a record in the subform when the parent form is unsaved causes the parent record to be saved. You might want to check if there is any code in the Insert and Update events of the main form that would cause a requery of the main form on the insert of a new record (triggered by editing the subform).

But I would still suggest that the best architecture is to avoid this kind of possible scenario by loading only single records, so there is no other record to jump to. That would certainly limit the possibilities of where the user could end up when the problem occurs.

Comment: "creating a record in the subform when the parent form is unsaved causes the parent record to be saved. " As soon as you click anywhere in the subform area Access will save the main record. However I generally disagree with the approach of a separate dialog. Or rather I see no reason for it. One form for inserts and updates should work and work well. And if Access has a bug in these circumstances then it should be fixed by MS

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't design these forms, and the users (salesmen, admin, management, engineers) are all accustomed to creation & editing in the same form. Using an identical unbound form that inserts the record in SQL as you suggest has occurred to me (actually I do this already in a number of other creation-only dialogs) only I don't know how I would handle populating the subform items, and I would like to avoid having to rewrite all these forms if I don't have to. I will check those events, but I know there are some forms that exhibit this behavior that have no vba. Thanks

Comment: "Some forms that exhibit this behavior have no vba"  Ok, that's good to know.

Comment: What about using the form in ADD mode? When you open it in ADD mode, there is one blank new record loaded in the form. When you save, you can change out of Add mode, but you'll still only have the single record loaded, so you shouldn't have something happening that causes you to jump to another record, because there is no other record to jump to.

Comment: Tony, you say "One form for inserts and updates should work and work well." But my experience has been one of strugging with making this work seamlessly, particularly in the area of cancelling an add record. There are also issues when your form's recordsource is not based on a single table, but has outer joins (there are plenty of good reasons for needing to do that) -- it's often helpful to create the record for the main table first and then load it into the form for editing. I also think it's useful to restrict the first step of creating a new record to just the required fields.

Comment: @dfenton tried that, no change. Also tried opening the form in "Data Entry" mode on adds, still does it.

Comment: When I suggested opening in ADD mode, what I was referring to was DATA ENTRY mode. I don't understand how in that mode your form can jump to another record, since there are no other records loaded except the brand-new blank record that's created when you open in that mode.

Comment: I guess I'll know more tomorrow when I get a chance to run it up myself.

Comment: Seems that setting Data Entry mode does fix it, one user was reporting it was still jumping last week after I added this to one of the forms. But a week later, it hasn't jumped since. I think they were getting mixed up between one of the unmodified forms. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen behavior 'like' this when there are multiple ways of doing the same thing. (i.e.  tabbing out of the textbox triggering the lostfocus vs clicking a button) So make sure that this isn't the case, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is coused by merge replication trigger. In this trigger (this problem strart from sql 2005 server , in SQL 2000 server this not nake problems) replication insert some data in replication tables with identities and access get this number of identity instead real form indentity insert. I read that access use @@IDENTITY insetad of SCOPE_IDENTITY and this is problem . To avoid this you should change merge trigger in way that in insert trigger on begining you save current value from @@identity in variable and on the end of trigger insert value in temp table as identity with start value of what is written in variable. this will correct @@iddentity and acces will get right value.

at begin of trigger
 DECLARE @identity int
 DECLARE @strsql varchar(128)
 set @identity=@@IDENTITY
ar end something like
 set @strsql='select identity(int,'+CAST(@identity as varchar(15)) +',1) as id into #temp'
 exec(@strsql)
et the and it should be placed between
    if @@error <> 0 
        goto FAILURE
and
    return

Problem in acces will erace not only on form but directly in ODBC link table too.

I'm looking for way how to add this automaticly to merge replication trigger (mainly insert).

Comment: While the point about SCOPE_IDENITY() in a scenario with triggers is good, there's no evidence that that has anything to do with this question so far as I can see. Can you explain how your answer is actually relevant here? Or are you asking a new question entirely?

Answer (score 1):

This is bug in Access and SQL comunication. Access take identity of new record from @@IDENTITY and when you finish entering record it reload data based on value from @@IDENTITY value from SQL. In SQL 200 inserted merge trigger and Acces usualy work ok. From SQL 2005 merge trigger have some part in which data are entered in some merge replication table which have identity to and change value of @IDDENTITY form that of newly entered rcord from Access.

One solution is to chanege all merege insert trigger to save @IDDENTITY on begining of it in variable and at the end of trigger insert dumy record in #temp table as identity column with starting value of variable previosly saved.

This solution I found somewhere the net when before week I was affected with this problem too. I was moving database from SQL 200 to SQL 2008 and then I found this problem with identity in Access. I suspect replication because when I was removing one of subscription all start to work well but after recreating it erased again.

I use this for solving problem (takem from somewhere on net).

at the begining of merge insert trigger

DECLARE @identity int

DECLARE @strsql varchar(128)

set @identity=@@IDENTITY

and at the end of merge insert trigger

set @strsql='select identity(int,'+CAST(@identity as varchar(15)) +',1) as id into #temp'

exec(@strsql)

last code should be placed on the place of /*insert end on this place */ in merge replication code

if @@error <> 0

goto FAILURE

/*insert end on this place */

return

But I'm searching for a way to do that automaticly for all existing merge trigger on publication and on all existing merge trigger on existing and future subscriptions.

Comment: Again, you've posted yet another answer when you should instead start a question of your own. There is actually no real evidence that the problem the original poster had is related to the trigger/SCOPE_IDENTITY() issue.